# Weird behaviour inverting float

Tags: python, python-3.x

With Python 3.4.3

```
int(1 / 1e-3)
```

1000

```
int(1 / 1e-4)
```

10000

```
int(1 / 1e-5)
```

**99999**

```
int(1 / 1e-6)
```

1000000

```
int(1 / 1e-7)
```

10000000

Bug or Feature? Any particular reason?

Comment: floats are not exact

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Perl shows the same result: > perl -e 'print(int(1 / 1e-5), "\n")'  # so it's probably inherent in the underlying C float/double format.

Comment: @cdlane Thank you, exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

floating point numbers aren't exact. Only binary numbers are.

```
>>> '%.25f' % 1e-5
'0.0000100000000000000008180'
>>> '%.25f' % (1/1e-5)
'99999.9999999999854480847716331'
```

So `1/1e-5` is less than `100000` and `int` cuts off the fractal part.
Converting to int, rounding is the answer:

```
>>> int(round(1/1e-5))
100000
```